# Import json data using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

Form a third party system deserialize json data to the object/class format and write data into a SQL Server table from a asp.net web api. When I run the below code I run into the following error

> cannot convert json collection to string

I am using System.Web.Extensions dll to deserialize json data.

JSON:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "Id":"1",
         "Student":"T code",
         "Grade":"Test code"
      }
   ],
   "Token":"",
   "header":[
      "Id",
      "Student",
      "Grade"
   ],
   "Rowcount":1
}
```

My model:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Student { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}

public class AllStudents
{
    public IList<SData> data { get; set; }
}
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Post(Student studentjson)
{
    IList<SData> StudentList = studentjson.data;
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    Student StudentObj = serializer.Deserialize<Student>(studentjson.data.ToString());

    string SQLConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;            
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        foreach (var student in StudentObj.data)
        {
            if (writetotbl(conn, student))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Success : " + student.Student);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error : " + student.Student);
            }
        }
    }           
}

static bool writetotbl(SqlConnection conn, studentjson StudentObj)
{
    try
    {
        string query = @"INSERT INTO [dbo].[student] ([student]) VALUES (@student)";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@student", StudentObj.student));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your post method does not have json argument .. and i don't think you need to serialize json in webapi.. you neee ti ellaborate a bit

Comment: @CodingYoshi: I still get cannot explicitly convert to type error.

Comment: @Aamir: Could you please let me point me to some example of not having to deserialize json in webapi.

Comment: IList<SData> StudentList = studentjson.data; Why you wrote this if you are not using StudentList  anywhere. I feel this will break as you  studentjson.data is string.

Comment: The model binder will deserialise your data automatically if you have a matching C# class. Your model is confusing though - you have a "Student" object as the input, then you expect there to be a "data" property on it, but that's not defined in your Student C# class, so is unlikely to exist. But why have a list of Students inside a single student? Structure makes no sense. And your code above will also not compile for other reasons. Is this your real code?

Comment: can you please post your json data and explain your business case?

Comment: @Aamir: I have added json to the original post and I am trying to write this data to a table.

Comment: You can use Newtonsoft and change the parameter type to JObject, and then deserialize it to the IList<Student> or try deserializing to AllStudents

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing should help understanding a bit

Comment: What is `SData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your model classes should be like this.

```
public class Student
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Student { get; set; }
    public string Grade { get; set; }
}

public class RequestModel
{
    public List<Student> data { get; set; }
    public string Token { get; set; }
    public List<string> header { get; set; }
    public int Rowcount { get; set; }
}
```

you do not need an extra serializer on web api.  asp.net web api  supports json-xml media types by default.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(RequestModel studentjson)
    {
        string SQLConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(SQLConnectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                foreach (var student in studentjson.data)
                {
                    if (writetotbl(conn, student.Student))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Id:{0}, Student:{1}, Grade:{2}", student.Id, student.Student, student.Grade));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error : " + student.Student);
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // make sure the connection is closed
                if (conn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                    conn.Close();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```